# Setting Data from Axios GET

Tags: vue.js, axios, vue-reactivity

I know there are similar questions to this but i've tried the solutions and nothing seems to be working

My code takes user input, makes a axios get request based off that input and aims to assign the data to the array staffs[]

```
export default {
    data(){
        return{
            staffs: [],
            userInput:'',
            errors: '',
        }
    },
    created:function(){
        bus.$on('search-data',inputData =>{
        axios.get('http://localhost:4000/stafftest?username='+inputData)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data))
            this.staffs = response.data.data
        })
        .catch(error =>{
            console.log(error)
        })
        })
    },  
}
```

Similar issue to what everyone else has asked, the axios request is made successfully but it won't assign data to the array[image]

Here's a combo of things i tried:

- https://codeshare.io/ammpP4 https://codeshare.io/G798xD
  https://codeshare.io/2Ewk1P https://codeshare.io/GqDPPk
- https://codeshare.io/GLbwwp

tried changing it to function(response) etc and having a var self=this, yet none of it seems to work

I even set up another test page which queries a pokemon API and the data assigmemt went smoothly, which leaves me confused as to why in this case on this certain page it won't work

Appreciate any ideas to get this fixed

Thanks

Comment: You are doing request on `created` hook, i think the `inputData` is empty at this point, since user didnt have time to type something. Btw - do you get any errors in browser console?

Comment: Sorry, should have clairfied. The input is coming from a previous page and gets transferred successfully, it ties into the AXIOS request and it's all done as expected.

I have 1 warning in my console 'Use of Mutation Events is deprecated. Use MutationObserver instead.' And i think this is related to a plugin being used?? Looked it up and people has put it down to that, unsure if relevant for current issue